# Display Menu & logo in center of the page

Tags: html, css

I have a logo & menu, displaying in the center of the page in the entire site as [here](http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com/).

[image]

but in only one page, it's displaying a bit to the left. I want to display that menu at the center center of the page as shown [here](http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com/customized-mobile-cases).

[image]

### CSS:

```
.ms-topmenu .ms-label {
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: none;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 14.75px 15px;
}

.ms-megamenu .anchor_mbmenu {
    background: rgb(7, 70, 102);
    padding: 8px 0;
    display: none;
}

.ms-megamenu .text-right {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Because of width:1200px. Change it to 1000px and  you are done.

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe there i no issue one has scroll in the page and another not so it is looking you changes its not an issue.

Comment: @IqbalPasha Thanks  for support. but client want like that only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go in your styles.css  and change

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1224px)
.cms-customized-mobile-cases #header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1200px;
}
```

to

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1224px)
.cms-customized-mobile-cases #header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

The page is having a extra class '[cms-customized-mobile-cases](http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com/customized-mobile-cases)' in the body tag which is causing a width of header to override to 1200px , which is causing the menu to shift a little  left remove this class from body tag and you will get the desired menu.

Here is the class which is causing the problem:

```
.cms-customized-mobile-cases #header {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1200px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to apply this below css will may solve issue.

```
html {
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;  /* remove scrollbar space */
    background: transparent;  /* optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}
/* optional: show position indicator in red */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #FF0000;
}
```